# how to write dynamic excel file (number of column can exceed) into java objects using apache poi

Tags: java, excel, automated-tests, apache-poi

I understand that we can create model class whose each instance variable will be bound to each excel column like below

```
class emp{
    String name;
    String empId;

   //getter and setter method of each
}
```

### excel file:

### name    |    empid

abc     |    123

bcd     |    3232

xyz     |    ee32

how to handle this case when number of column in excel increases dynamically

Comment: Use `Map` instead of `Emp` object

Comment: I dont think it will work. I was creating List<Emp<empID, EmpObj>>. however issue is that if excel column changes then code needs to be changed. Any can you post code snapshot of logic

Answer (score 1):

I would doing this using a kind of table model. A `ExcelTableModel` similar to the [javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html).

Complete example showing a blueprint of this approach:

```java
import java.io.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;

public class UseExcelTableModel {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream("ExcelFile.xlsx"));
        Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
        ExcelTableModel excelTableModel = new ExcelTableModel(sheet);

        System.out.println(excelTableModel.getColumnCount());
        System.out.println(excelTableModel.getRowCount());

        System.out.println(excelTableModel.getColumnNames());
        System.out.println(excelTableModel.getData());

        System.out.println(excelTableModel.getColumnName(1));
        System.out.println(excelTableModel.getValueAt(2, 1));

        workbook.close();
    }
}
```

```java
import java.util.Vector;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DataFormatter;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;

public class ExcelTableModel {
    private Vector<String> columnNames;
    private Vector<Vector<String>> data;
    private DataFormatter dataFormatter = new DataFormatter();

    public ExcelTableModel(Sheet sheet) {
        this.columnNames = new Vector<String>();
        this.data = new Vector<Vector<String>>();

        int firstRow = sheet.getFirstRowNum();
        Row colNamesRow = sheet.getRow(firstRow);
        int firstCol = colNamesRow.getFirstCellNum();
        int lastColP1 = colNamesRow.getLastCellNum();

        for (int c = firstCol; c < lastColP1; c++) {
            Cell cell = colNamesRow.getCell(c);
            String columnName = dataFormatter.formatCellValue(cell);
            this.columnNames.add(columnName);
        }

        int lastRow = sheet.getLastRowNum();
        for (int r = firstRow + 1; r < lastRow + 1; r++) {
            Vector<String> cells = new Vector<String>();
            Row row = sheet.getRow(r);
            if (row == null) {
                row = sheet.createRow(r);
            }
            for (int c = firstCol; c < lastColP1; c++) {
                Cell cell = row.getCell(c);
                String cellValue = dataFormatter.formatCellValue(cell);
                cells.add(cellValue);
            }
            this.data.add(cells);
        }
    }

    public int getColumnCount() {
        return this.columnNames.size();
    }

    public int getRowCount() {
        return this.data.size();
    }

    public String getColumnName(int columnIndex) {
        return this.columnNames.get(columnIndex);
    }

    public String getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        return this.data.get(rowIndex).get(columnIndex);
    }

    public Vector getColumnNames() {
        return this.columnNames;
    }

    public Vector getData() {
        return this.data;
    }

    // More getters and setters...
}
```

The first sheet in `ExcelFile.xlsx` can be something like this:

[image]

As you see, the table will be got from the used range and the first row of the used range will be got as column names.

Comment: Thanks @Axel ... this makes absolute sense.

Comment: @Mr. Polywhirl: Please explain the reason of editing my code.

Comment: I did not edit the code, I simply formatted the post as a whole. Seeing each class as a separate block of code alleviates scrolling through the code to see when a new class starts. I also adjusted the indentation for improved readability.

Comment: @Mr. Polywhirl: And that was necessary doing second time again even if I had shown that I disagree with that by rolling back your edit? Thanks a lot Mr. Headteacher.